# JEditorPane wraps in the middle of characters within words in java version less than 1.6

Tags: swing

In my application, I have a JTextPane within a JScrollPane which in turn is in a panel. Here the wrapping happens at characters even in the middle of words. So the view is a word is being split in rows when seen by the user. However, this happens with java 1.4 and 1.5 but not with 1.6? In 1,6 it wraps only at word endings. Do any of the gurus here have a clue on this? Can you help me?

Does the version 1.4 code htmleditor kit formats the view in the viewfactory that way? Or is this a problem in my app code? Pls clarify Let me know if you need details further

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are relying on formatting or styling of the text a way around it is to use a `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` and call `textArea.setLineWrap(true)` and `textArea.setWordWrap(false)`.